# SQL Pivot row and column

Tags: sql, sql-server

With my small table

```
skill   dept     startdate     starttime
good    A        2020-09-01    08:00:00.0000000
good    A        2020-09-03    08:50:00.0000000
bad     A        2020-09-04    18:00:00.0000000
bad     B        2020-09-05    09:53:00.0000000
avg     B        2020-09-06    13:00:05.0000000
avg     B        2020-09-07    13:50:05.0000000
```

My query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        skill, MIN(starttime) AS MinTime,Max(starttime) AS MaxTime,  startdate 
    FROM 
        table2
    group by starttime, startdate, skill
 )t       
PIVOT(
    COUNT(skill) 
    FOR skill IN ([Mon], [Tue], [Wed], [Thu], [Fri], [Sat],  [Sun])
)
AS pivot_table;
```

Results

```
MinTime             MaxTime             startdate   Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
08:00:00.0000000    08:00:00.0000000    2020-09-01  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
08:50:00.0000000    08:50:00.0000000    2020-09-03  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
09:53:00.0000000    09:53:00.0000000    2020-09-05  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13:00:05.0000000    13:00:05.0000000    2020-09-06  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13:50:05.0000000    13:50:05.0000000    2020-09-07  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000    2020-09-04  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Not sure why not count total group by skill field?
Hopefully some one can point the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: None of your rows, have the value `'Mon'`, `'Tue'`, `'Wed'`, etc for the column `skill`, so of course all the values are `0`. If you had `FOR skill IN ([good], [bad], [avg])` you would get counts.

Comment: I want the count fall in to week day. Say the date 2020-09-01 should have 1 count on Tue,  So if we use FOR skill IN ([good], [bad], [avg]) then it will extend another column which I don't want. Hope that make sense.

Comment: In your GROUP BY it should just be skill and not include starttime, startdate no?

Comment: If I remove group starttime, startdate then error. Column 'table2.startdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If the startdate is included in the select list then the min and max starttimes are always be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
      SELECT 
          skill, MIN(starttime) AS MinTime,Max(starttime) AS MaxTime,  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, startdate) as startdate
      FROM 
          table_2
      group by starttime, startdate, skill
   ) t
  PIVOT(
      COUNT(Skill) 
      FOR startdate IN (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,  Sunday)
  )
  AS pivot_table;
```